# ASHorizontalScrollView not showing all elements

Tags: ios, uitableview, scrollview

I'm trying to implement a ASHorizontalScrollView (just like App Strore horizontal scroll menu). I'm adjusting it's frame but the last element never shows, it's size looks bigger than the super view. You can see the last element it's there but can never bring it on.

[image: I touch and drag to force to show the last element]

I configured the size of the horizontal scrollview as the size of the tablecell it's allocated.

My question is HOW DO I SET HORIZONTAL SCROLLVIEW width to show all elements?

this is how i set it at the CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier  = "cell"
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        //First row must be ASHorizontalScrollView
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let horizontalScrollView = ASHorizontalScrollView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height))


            //sample code of how to use this scroll view
            horizontalScrollView.uniformItemSize = CGSize(width: 74.4, height: 74.4)

            //this must be called after changing any size or margin property of this class to get acurrate margin
            horizontalScrollView.setItemsMarginOnce()
            //create buttons for cell 1
            var buttons = [UIView]()


            var choosedColor : UIColor!
            //Loop creating buttons and  customizing them
            for i in 0...contacts.count - 1 {

                var aButton = CustomButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 74, height: 74))

                //Choose a color depending of the index it's showing
                switch i % contacts.count {
                case 0:
                    choosedColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.639, green: 0.780, blue: 0.294, alpha: 1.0)
                    break
                case 1:
                    choosedColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.807, green: 0.258, blue: 0.317, alpha: 1.0)
                    break
                case 2:
                    choosedColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.286, green: 0.509, blue: 0.772, alpha: 1.0)
                    break
                default:
                    choosedColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.639, green: 0.780, blue: 0.294, alpha: 1.0)
                }

                //set chosen color to button and round it up 
                aButton.backgroundColor = choosedColor

                aButton.setContactName(contactName: contacts[i])

                buttons.append(aButton)

            }

            horizontalScrollView.addItems(buttons)
            var x = horizontalScrollView.calculateMarginBetweenItems()


            cell.contentView.addSubview(horizontalScrollView)
            horizontalScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: horizontalScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: cell.frame.height))

            cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: horizontalScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem:cell.contentView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))




        }
        else{
            //cell must be message cell


        }

     return cell
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Readjusting the table view with a frame (equal to the storyboard) configured all elements correctly